# How to force instruments not to close app once automation scripts end?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios-ui-automation

Is there a possible way I can force instruments to let the app keep running when my automation script ends?

Use case: I want to run leaks command once the sing-out within the app is done, but let the application be alive after the automation script has simulated a few actions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to work with applications running in background:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124159/Hour-21-Building-Background-Aware-Applications

And search about the method:

> beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

It's responsable to maintain the script continue to run.

After it finishes, you call:

> endBackgroundTask